# python - Saving images to generated directories

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hopefully this is a quick one for someone.  its been annoying me for a while now.

I can create the directory and save the images to the directory where the script is ran, but i cannot figure how to save the images to its specific folder created for that specific advert.

Would someone be able to  shed some light on this please?

```
    gundir = soup.find("title").text #keep - folder creation for each advert using title
    gun_folders = os.makedirs(gundir)


    for img in imgs:
      clean = re.compile('src=".*?"')
      strings = clean.findall(str(img))    
      for string in strings:
         imgUrl = string.split('"')[1]
         filename = imgUrl.split('/')[-1]
         resp = requests.get(imgUrl, stream=True)
         local_file = open(filename, 'wb')
         resp.raw.decode_content = True
         shutil.copyfileobj(resp.raw, local_file)
         del resp
```

I understand the above code does what its supposed to do, but its not enough for what i wish it to do.

Could someone point me in the direction on how to achieve what i'm after?

Thanks!

Comment: assuming that u are on a virtual environment, you should concatenate the path  like this :  local_file = open('{}/{}'.format(gun_folders ,filename), 'wb')

Comment: @lagripe Cheers ill give it a go here at lunch time and let you know if its what im after.

Comment: `local_file = open(gun_folders + '/' + filename, 'wb')`

Comment: @lagripe - that worked ok.  got to give it a test run.  If you want to stick it up as an answer i can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String concatenation

```
local_file = open('{}/{}'.format(gun_folders ,filename), 'wb')
```